# How to calculate SNR with White gaussian noise

Tags: noise, snr, radar

Im working on a Pulsed Doppler Radar

What is the way to calculate the SNR (with WGN)? What will be the lowest SNR for detectability?

Im using matched-filter(xcorr) to process the signal+noise.

My signal+noise are:

```
noiseGauss=(1/sqrt(2))*noiseAmp*(randn(1, length(t)) + 1i*randn(1, length(t)));

recv_sig = noiseGauss + (h_t(t) .* exp(-1i*2*pi*fc*t));
```

Is it true that Power_in equals to:

```
powerIn = abs( sum(transmitted_sig) ) .^2 ; ?
```

Thanks alot in advance!

Comment: If you are correlating to a matched (and noise free) signal, then you can normalize the correlation (by the standard deviation of the signal x the standard deviation of your replica signal) and then from that compute the SNR: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/38670/how-can-i-find-snr-peaq-and-odg-values-by-comparing-two-audios/38679#38679

Comment: Itay, please read my 2nd anwer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.-** From :

[**An Introduction to Signals and Noise in Electrical Communications**](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Communication-Systems-Solutions-Introduction-Electrical/dp/0070099588/ref=sr_1_6?crid=3O6YLVNUXE38F&keywords=communication%20systems%20bruce%20carlson&qid=1673637400&s=books&sprefix=communcation%20systems%20bruce%20carlson%2Cstripbooks%2C62&sr=1-6)

Author : Bruce Carlson

Search for much cheaper copies readily available online.

The sought figure-of-merit is   **SNR=S/N**

`S` : signal power

`N` : noise power

`s` signal may be anything to measure, over time, for then calculate signal power.

`s` is often measured to control work [kg*m] or [lb*ft] . Work is, or should be, proportional to money [$] or [£] or equivalent.

**Power** measures **capacity to generate work**.

When working with electrical signals power is [V^2/Ohm] or [A^2*Ohm].

Most relevant literature obviate what **impedance** value(s) exactly to use, because it depends upon what network is used.

So [CARLSON] included assume 1[Ohm] and develop accordingly. So

```
S=mean(s^2)
N=mean(n^2)
```

but receivers always catch `S+N` , not just `S` .

**2.-** **Refreshing Random Variables**

From [**this**](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Ecshalizi/36-220/lecture-6.pdf) Carnegie Mellon University lecture

in general : `mean((x+y)^2)=(mean(x+y))^2+var(x+y)`

**2.1.-** For **signals** `mean(s^2)=(mean(s))^2+var(s)`

If the link budget has been correctly designed and since signals and pulses to detect are supposed to be known
on the receiver side

```
(mean(s))^2 >> var(s) and S ~ (mean(s))^2
```

**2.2.-** For **noise** it's the contrary.

It's in the nature of noise `var(n) >> mean(n)`

**3.-** **AWG** `n` is supposed to be **uncorrelated** to `s`

in general `mean((x+n)^2)=mean(x^2)+2*mean(x*n)+mean(n^2)`

So even if point **1.-** takes place, meaning

`mean(s^2)>>mean(n^2)` and

```
mean(s^2)+mean(n^2) ~ mean(s^2)
```

if noise `n` is is correlated to signal `s` that the term `2*mean(x*n)` cannot be neglected

However, for a satisfatory system design, with **A**dditive **W**hite **G**ausian **AWG** Noise **only**, in absence of interference, or any other **non-AWG** noise correlated to signal, then

```
S>>N and S+N ~ S
```

**3.-** So

```
(mean(s))^2/(var(n)^2) % SNR linear
```

same as

```
20*log10(abs(var(s)))-20*log10(abs(var(n)))  % SNR in [dB]
```

**4.-** I found [this](https://webdemo.inue.uni-stuttgart.de/webdemos/02_lectures/uebertragungstechnik_1/qam_constellation_diagram_from_snr/index.php?id=2#) interesting website where **SNR** is calculated from **QAM** constellation parameters

**QAM webdemo**,
Institute of Telecommunications, University of Stuttgart, Germany, Jan. 2023.

Author : Michael Bernhard

**5.-** [**This Mathworks page**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html) shows how to use MATLAB command `snr` for *narrow band signals*.

**6.-** For **digital signals** you should focus on **Eb/N0** rather than **SNR**, **SNR** being important, but digital signals quality is about having

- enough pulse or **bit enery** `Eb`
- over **noise power spectral density**, aka **noise power per Hz** `N0`

rather than signal Watts over Noise Watts (SNR).

Often you will read **EbN0** instead of **Eb/N0** both being the same, it's just *'simplified'* notation.

**Eb/N0 101** reading, by Jim Pearce [**available here**](http://www.sss-mag.com/ebn0.html).

However

All above said is for **narrow band signals only**.

For broadband signals more or less complicated expressions may or nay not be available and it may be far more practical to obtain **direct measurements**.

**7.-** An example: **OFDM signals** are considered broadband because several close carriers are often used and the overall bandwidth being much larger than the band for each single carrier.

An available detailed explanation how to estimate **SNR** for **OFDM** systems is available in this thesis :

**Pilot-Based Time Domain SNR Estimation for Broadcasting OFDM Systems**

Authors : Abid Muhammad Khan, Varun Jeoti, Muhammad Zaka Ur Rehman, Muhammad Taha Jilani, Omer Chugtai, Mubashir Hussain Rehmani.

Journal of Computer Networks and Communications, vol. 2018, Article ID 9319204, 8 pages, 2018.
https://doi.org/10.1155/2018/9319204

[**Complete text available in Hindawi**](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jcnc/2018/9319204/)

Particularly [**this table**](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/jcnc/2018/9319204/tab1/) shows a couple ways **SNR** can be estimated for **OFDM** signals as defined in this text.

And I say it again : Reliable **measurements** with calibrated instruments are the best way to really know what **SNR** a signal really has.

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

**1.-** MATLAB already has command `snr` to directly calculate **Signal-to-Noise** ratios

command `snr` details [available here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html)

**2.-** the signal may have also have **intermodulation**, either from transmitter or caused by reflections along the channel(s)

The other 2 similar measurements to `snr` but not the same are **Total Harmonic Distortion (THD)** and **Signal to Noise and Distortion Ratio SINAD**.

Both also have dedicated commands:

Details about command `thd` [available here](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/thd.html?searchHighlight=thd&s_tid=srchtitle_thd_1).

Details about command `sinad` [available here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/sinad.html).

**3.-** Some literature also use Signal-to-Interference **SIR** along with **SNR** or in some scenarios where intereference >> noise, like some urban mobile communications, completely ignore SNR and use **SIR** only.

There's no command for **SIR** because deciding what is noise and what is interference is not a straight away task for a MATLAB base command.

**4.-** To calculate detectability first you have to define an acceptable **probabilty of detection**, or equivalently, and acceptable **probability of error** by error comprising both missing pulses and taking noise/interference as valid pulses.

Do you have this figure?

If you supply a sample of the signal I may be able to supply some MATLAB code for you to start with.

**5.-** To truly calculate **signal power** out of signal amplitude samples one has to include imedance.

Because you mentioned *pulse radar* you have to be careful with the time window or cycle used to calculate **signal power**.

If you more than one pulse in same cycle used to calculate signal power you have to average, but then **SNR** is going to be averaged, meaning one cannot tell at what time within each cycle did SNR spike.

Comment: thanks for th reply! I'll clarify a bit: Ive been told that the SNR = Power_in / Var(wgn) = |Signal|^2 / Var (wgn). My signal is = exp(1i*pi*(t-0.5*Pw).^2*B/Pw).*exp(1i*2*pi*fc*t), where B is bandwidth, Pw is transmission time = 2 usec, and this pules is transmitted every PRI=5 usec. is it safe to say that |signal|^2 = 1 therefore my SNR = 1/Var(wgn) ?

Comment: Itay read my 2nd answer that's been somehow pushed up ahead of the 1st answer.